# Как остановить анимацию?

Tags: java, android

Анимация:

```
android:duration="1000"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toYScale="0.9" />

 Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
```

Анимация работает, работает постоянно,то что нужно,но есть такой нюанс:
 выбрал R.id.b1: анимация запустилась и работает, выбрал R.id.b2: запустилась анимация но и на R.id.b1: продолжает выполняться анимация,а нужно остановить

```
  rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {
                    arr_imageB[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                           //запускаю анимацию
                           v.startAnimation(anim);

                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.b1: {


                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);


                                }
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b2:

                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);

                                        }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b3:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);

                                        }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b4:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                                         }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b5: {
                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                                }
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b6: {
                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);

                                }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b7:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);

                                        }
                                break;
                            }

                            return false;  }

                    });
                }

                return rootViewB;

            }


        }
```

//тут я запускаю мелодию и проверяю на повторный запуск мелодии

```
 stopPlayerIfNeeded();
       playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
```

про v.clearAnimation(); я слышал,только как применить к моему коду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
    arr_imageB[index].clearAnimation(); 
}
```